# i3wm: Fn key causes certain apps to crash (Manjaro on ThinkPad E570)

Tags: manjaro, i3, d-bus, thinkpad

Running i3wm on a Lenovo Thinkpad E570. Everything else typically works just fine. However, pressing the `Fn` key instantly kills Firefox (if open), all tray icons, and dunst. Some notes:

- There is nothing in my `.config/i3/config` that relates to XF86WakeUp (which `Fn` maps to, for some reason).
- This problem does not occur when using KDE (i.e. this problem seems related to i3wm, not Xorg/Wayland).
- Once this crash has happened, these apps can be reopened and are then no longer affected.
- I've also had issues with opening some apps such as Dolphin, which shows the following error when opened in a terminal:

`"Session bus not found\nTo circumvent this problem try the following command (with Linux and bash)\nexport $(dbus-launch)"`

- I can then use `export $(dbus-launch)` to run it from the terminal, but it only applies to the terminal session; running this command from dbar also has no effect. Could this be a related problem? This only happens after the crash.

Any  insights into strange i3 or dbus behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I looked to see if there were any alternative or supplementary `dbus` packages, and found `dbus-x11` in Manjaro's `core` repository. Upon installing that (which replaced the normal `dbus` package), both the crashing error and the problem with Dolphin are no longer occurring.

As such, I'm inclined to believe that **I simply had the wrong version of** `dbus` **installed**! Problem solved. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm using archlinux, `yaourt install dbus-x11` (aur development) replace the previous dubs also works well.

Comment: Pacman was actually just fine, and in fact I'd recommend using `yay` instead of `yaourt`; the latter is deprecated and is no longer being developed.